# Как сделать горизонтальный скролл под таблицей

Tags: html, css

Имеется таблица со скроллом на мобильной версии
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вызвал вот так:

```
<div><table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>№</th>
<th>Наименование</th>
<th>Допускаемая нагрузка, кН</th>
<th>d</th>
<th>s, не менее</th>
<th>Длина развернутой детали</th>
<th>Масса, кг</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>01 ОСТ 24.125.102</td>
<td>8,8</td>
<td>М12</td>
<td>14</td>
<td>129</td>
<td>0,31</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>02 ОСТ 24.125.102</td>
<td>14,7</td>
<td>М16</td>
<td>18</td>
<td>160</td>
<td>0,61</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td>03 ОСТ 24.125.102</td>
<td>23,5</td>
<td>М20</td>
<td>23</td>
<td>183</td>
<td>0,96</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>4</td>
<td>04 ОСТ 24.125.102</td>
<td>33,3</td>
<td>М24</td>
<td>28</td>
<td>216</td>
<td>1,72</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>5</td>
<td>05 ОСТ 24.125.102</td>
<td>53,9</td>
<td>М30</td>
<td>34</td>
<td>268</td>
<td>2,81</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>6</td>
<td>06 ОСТ 24.125.102</td>
<td>78,4</td>
<td>М36</td>
<td>38</td>
<td>333</td>
<td>4,79</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>7</td>
<td>07 ОСТ 24.125.102</td>
<td>107,9</td>
<td>М42</td>
<td>58</td>
<td>422</td>
<td>12,90</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>8</td>
<td>08 ОСТ 24.125.102</td>
<td>147,0</td>
<td>М48</td>
<td>58</td>
<td>422</td>
<td>12,40</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table></div>
    

table {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно сделать скролл ПОД таблицей

Comment: Например, [вот так](https://i.imgur.com/iAoxNr4.png) можно сделать.

Comment: @yar85 , именно)

Comment: @yar85 , только я не совсем понимаю, как это реализовать

Comment: Реализовать можно либо паддингом контейнера / невидимой строкой (tr), либо графическим редактором. Последнее проще, т.к. верстать не потребуется.

Comment: @yar85 хотел вас попросить показать трюк с tr, ибо мне кажется, что решение нетривиальное

Comment: @is73dre Необходимо создать обертку для таблицы, к которой применить стили. Пример - jsfiddle.net/d8bnx230

Comment: @soledar10, проблема в том, что я так пробовал до этого, и скролл всё равно на том же месте)

Comment: @MaximLensky , под таблицей

Comment: @MaximLensky добавил в вопрос

Comment: @highpassion, да вполне тривиальное: вот [демо (активация при вьюпорте <768)](https://cdpn.io/yar85/fullpage/qBmzwbb), вот [гифка (если демо не откроется)](https://i.imgur.com/64Bmg77.gif), и вот [сырцы](https://codepen.io/yar85/pen/qBmzwbb?editors=1100).

Comment: @MaximLensky по прежнему на том же месте) Скролл находится в пределах таблицы, а мне необходимо, чтобы он был прям под таблицей

Comment: padding-bottom добавьте

Comment: @MaximLensky возникла странная ситуация, когда я пробовал это сделать раньше, ничего не работало, сейчас работает.... Всем спасибо за потраченное время!

Comment: @yar85 красиво, благодарю